# Projected area vs area of infinitesimally small arbirtrary shape in projective transformation

Tags: projective-geometry, computer-vision

What I am trying to find is a formula relating the projected area $A_p$ to the area $A$ of a planar object of arbirtrary shape, position and orientation in 3D space when subject to a projective transformation $P$ to 2D space, given the object's position and its orientation (e.g. by a plane normal) in relation to the origin. I would like to find this formula for an infinitesimally small shape, so that it becomes shape-independent and relates perceived and real area of any point in 3D space given its "orientation" (if you can say that about a point).

How I have approached this so far is by imagining a circle in 3D space, described by a centre point and two points on its circumference who I assume to be lying on the end of the two half-axes described by the ellipse created after projective transformation and then relating the area of the circle and the ellipse, given the radius, centre point and normal of the circle. However, I can't quite get it infinitesimally small nor do I know if I can just define my two points on the circumference to be lying on the end of the two half-axes of the ellipse.
Is there a better approach? Does such a closed solution even exist and how does it look like?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "perceived area". Perhaps there is a better term to describe what you intended? Also the "real area" is better written as just "area" because that has a precise meaning. Perhaps what you want is a projective transformation from one plane to another plane? I don't understand why you need to bring 3D into this.

Comment: I think I'm using too many layman's terms here. What I mean is the relation of the area of said shape in 3D and 2D (after projective transformation).

Comment: You can easily find the area of an infinitesimal parallelogram given two side vectors using the cross product in 3D space. Under a projective transformation the image is a similar figure. The ratio of the two areas depends on the position of the given parallelogram I think unless it is actually an affine transformation. I see now that you actually mean projection from 3D to 2D space. The term "projective" did not immediately suggest that to me.

Comment: Would that hold only for infintesimally small parallelograms or would the shape-dependence disappear?

Comment: Notice my wording "depends on the position of the given parallelogram" unless using an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). The Wikipedia article states "Affine transformations do not respect lengths or angles; they multiply area by a constant factor". A projective transformation need not have the same property with respect to areas, but of course, it does so infinitesimally.

Comment: Assuming that I know the position of the parallelogram, it should thus be possible to calculate this area ratio for a projective transformation, which is what I am interested in, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a small circle centered at $\vec P$, in the plane defined by the orthonormal vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$. A point of the circle is

$$\vec P+r\cos\theta\,\vec u+r\sin\theta\,\vec v.$$

With a focal distance $f$ and the projection with the pole at the origin onto a plane parallel to $xy$,

$$\begin{cases}X=f\dfrac{P_x+r\cos\theta\,u_x+r\sin\theta\,v_x}{P_z+r\cos\theta\,u_z+r\sin\theta\,v_z},
\\Y=f\dfrac{P_y+r\cos\theta\,u_y+r\sin\theta\,v_y}{P_z+r\cos\theta\,u_z+r\sin\theta\,v_z}.\end{cases}$$

Now using the Taylor develoment to the first order, we can approximate with

$$\begin{cases}X=\dfrac f{P_z}\left(P_x+r\cos\theta\,(u_x-u_z\dfrac{P_x}{P_z})+r\sin\theta\,(v_x-v_z\dfrac{P_x}{P_z})\right),
\\Y=\dfrac f{P_z}\left(P_y+r\cos\theta\,(u_y-u_z\dfrac{P_y}{P_z})+r\sin\theta\,(v_y-v_z\dfrac{P_y}{P_z})\right).\end{cases}$$

The variable terms take the form

$$\begin{cases}\tilde X=ra\cos\theta+rb\sin\theta,\\\tilde Y=rc\cos\theta+rd\sin\theta,\end{cases}$$ which describe an ellipse. We get the area by

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{X\dot Y-Y\dot X}2\,dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ad-bc}2\,dt.$$

Hence the requested ratio is

$$ad-bc$$ where these coefficients are as given above.

Comment: Thanks. I can't quite follow your Taylor expansion unfortunately. When I develop around an arbitrary angle, my trigonometric functions disappear.

Comment: @Iridium: you develop on $r$.

Comment: Oh. Sometimes I miss the obvious, my bad.

Comment: I just noticed something: Shouldn't it be $bc - ad$?

Comment: @Iridium: I don't know.